# get custom attribute value with jquery

Tags: jquery

Trying to get attribute value with jQuery, then append it to element with class

```
<div id="data" class="democlass" data-author="Mr. Jhon Doe" data-cat="Technology" data-url="https://google.com"></div>

<p class="data-author"></p>
<p class="data-cat"></p>
<a href="#"></a>
```

```js
$("#data").each(function() {
    var author = $(this).attr("data-author");
    var cat = $(this).attr("data-cat");
});

$( document ).ready(function() {
    $( ".data-author" ).append(author);
    $( ".data-cat" ).append(cat);
});
```

Am I doing something wrong in the code? here is the sample [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LxyQzM)

Comment: variable in different scope

Comment: first why you are using `each` on `id` attribute ? and i didn't find more than one div to use each loop ?

Comment: Give [`$.data()`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.data/) a chance.

Comment: I'm sorry for that... I found that code by searching on SO and googling. I'm self-taught in jQuery..

Comment: your variable is not global

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Variables are in different scope so it will be `undefined`, so do both actions within the document ready handler. Although [`each()`](https://api.jquery.com/each/) is completely unnecessary here since `id` is unique(if there are multiple elements with same `id` then only the first element get selected).

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  // cache the element
  var $ele = $("#data");

  // append contents
  $( ".data-author" ).append($ele.attr("data-author"));
  $( ".data-cat" ).append($ele.attr("data-cat"));
});
```

---

**UPDATE :** You although use [`data()`](https://api.jquery.com/data/) method to get custom `data-*` attribute value.

```
$( ".data-author" ).append($ele.data("author"));
$( ".data-cat" ).append($ele.data("cat"));
```

Comment: @bona :  glad to help :)

Comment: can you please help me as my condition udpated in the question? I want to add url in the attribute, then use it as link target and link text.

Comment: @bona : `$(".data-cat").next().attr('href' , 'your value here')`

Comment: I mean to get the link from `data-url` attribute, then append it to `a` tag as link target and link text. btw thanks before

Comment: @bona `$(".data-cat").next().attr('href' , $ele.data('url'))`

Answer (score 0):

No need for each loop

```
$( document ).ready(function() { 
$( ".data-author" ).append($("#data").attr("data-author"));
$( ".data-cat" ).append($("#data").attr("data-cat"));
});
```